# Use the same colors as Visual Studio for prettify.css

Tags: feature-request, design, syntax-highlighting

I'm pretty sure stackoverflow already uses the same color as VS for everything except comments, which are displayed gray:

```
/* Test */
```

I think it's much better to display them in green-ish (same exact color as the default theme in Visual Studio).. Very often they contain useful information that should be easy to read, and gray on gray is not.

I recently made a `prettify.css` for my blog, so here it is. Everything is straight from VS except for numbers (`abc = 5;`) that are red instead of black.

```
.com { color: #008000; } /* <-- color of comments */
.str, .tag { color: #A31515; }
.kwd, .atv { color: #0000FF; }
.typ { color: #2B91AF; }
.lit, .atn { color: #FF0000; }
.pun, .pln { color: #000000; }
.dec { color: purple; }
```

Comment: The code looks pretty generic enough. I like VS colours but not everyone uses VS.

Comment: @Finglas: the color scheme is already VS's, except for comments, which would look better in green for the reasons specified above.

Comment: They may be default colours, but certainly are not standard. As a side note I do prefer green for comments however.

Comment: you haven't asked a question

Comment: @Matt, this is Meta. They don't always have to ask a question.

Comment: @Brandon - okay, didnt know that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prettify just creates elements in the DOM that match up with a style sheet.  As always, your browser will allow you to override any style definition you want in your own sheet.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer gray as the comments' color.

Comment: Me too; it makes it possible to squint slightly and only see the code, while the comments fade away into the darkness.