# Can c# comments be green and not light gray?

Tags: feature-request, design, syntax-highlighting

I'm pretty sure just about everybody in the universe who codes c# has configured their code comments to be green.  In fact, I don't know any language where people tend to color their comments in something other than a shade of green.  Except on StackOverflow.

[image]

Please don't make the code narwhal sad.  Change the CSS for code comments to a lovely shade of green!  Like sea green, algea green, or maybe seaweed green.

Comment: Sad? More like preggers there.

Comment: Sad, possibly pregnant and with dental problems. All the more reason to fulfill its wish, poor thing.

Comment: "I don't know any language where people tend to color their comments in something other than a shade of green". Er. Is this really a language thing?

Comment: You comment your code? Good on you.

Comment: @random: Code narwhal spends lots of time in his cubicle, drinking soda.  He doesn't get much exercise anymore.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Eh, I suppose not... More of an IDE default thing, I guess.

Comment: "configured their code comments to be green": unlikely... that's the default. I do tend to change it to maroon (as I tend to make all the colours darker for better contrast on a white background).

Comment: Mine are gray, I use an theme derived from Expression.  I wouldn't be opposed to the green, though.

Comment: Mine are also gray, I'm using a custom Oblivion theme, so they blend better into the background (where comments belong, in my opinion, they should help, not distract from code).

Comment: Wouldn't you know the freaks who don't have green comments would come out of the woodwork.  Freaks.

Comment: Now I'm opposed to the green.

Comment: `In fact, I don't know any language where people tend to color their comments in something other than a shade of green.` MonoDevelop uses by default blue and NetBeans' default comments are also gray...don't make me look it up in Eclipse! ;)

Comment: But...my comments are always in gray. I go out of my way to make them gray...

Comment: @Swati: ***FREEAAAAAAK!!!!!***

Comment: The narwhal is not fat, or pregnant; it's just that outside the water the gravity has that effect. Or that, or we would be wearing a diving mask.

Comment: Is that a narwhal, or did a manatee and a unicorn have a love child?

Comment: No, no, maroon is clearly the proper color!

Comment: oh, the irony. I already proposed this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37760/use-the-same-colors-as-visual-studio-for-prettify-css 2 years ago and it was downvoted and then closed as "too localized"

Comment: @koper I didn't see a sad narwhal on your question so I fail to see how they're similar :)

Answer (score 10):

For your convenience, here's a quick and dirty userscript that changes the code comments color to green (only on Stack Overflow):

> [**Green Comments**](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/103640.user.js)

it does nothing more than simply adding this global style:

```
code span.com { color: green; }
```

Comment: Richard suggestion `code span.com` ensure that only code comments are highlighted correctly.

Comment: @Loïc: I don't think that it's really necessary, as the current gray color is also defined on the global `.com` class in `all.css` on Stack Overflow, but I updated the script and my answer anyway ;-)

Comment: +1 for doing work for me.  However, I wish to impose my will over all, lest any narwhal be denied green comments, so *no accept for you!*

Comment: @Won't: No problemo, the accept should indeed go to a permanent fix for everyone (I also don't like my comments gray), but in the mean time, it's at least a solution for some narwals out there...

Comment: All of my unicorns approve this.

Answer (score 2):

If your browser (or extensions) are up to it applying a user style to the CSS selector

```
code span.com
```

will override the default styling.

Comment: Work?  *You want me to do work to fix this??*

Comment: Heinous.  Simply, heinous...

Comment: @Won't So you're on SO but so don't want a bit of (declarative) programming? :-)

Comment: Well, fretje posted not only a whole rule but also some userscript to apply it. You could have at least written the rule, if not the mozilla-specific boilerplate to ensure it's used only for SE sites (which would anyway be likely to miss some of less-well-known 2nd-level domain names, e.g. askubuntu.com or stackapps.com).

Answer (score 0):

For those of a chrome persuasion, I've just put together a [little extension](https://github.com/downloads/lexy0202/sogreencomments/sogreencomments.crx) to make the comments green.